# HTML "mailto:" not opening in new window

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

This is my first post.
I am trying to create a mailto link using 'templated' Javascript that takes the following excerpt from a JSON object:

```
var menu = {
"menu": [
     {
     "title": "let's talk",
     "link": "mailto:mrlevitas@yahoo.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Where '+menu.menu[i].link+' is replaced by "mailto:mrlevitas@yahoo.com"

```
for (i=0; i<menu.menu.length; i=i+1) {
     entry = '<li><a href="'+menu.menu[i].link+'">'+menu.menu[i].title+' </a></li>';
}
$("#navmenu:last").append(entry);
```

When I click on the page (http://mrlevitas.github.io), nothing happens in either chrome or firefox.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the

```
for (i=0; i<menu.menu.length; i=i+1) {
 entry = '<li><a href="'+menu.menu[i].link+'"  target="_BLANK">'+menu.menu[i].title+' </a></li>';
}
$("#navmenu:last").append(entry);
```

It opens a new window.

Comment: this is a response for other question. A `mailto:` link opens a program, not a tab

Answer (score 1):

It is browser settings specific, ie. it will behave differently depending on the user's browser settings. The user can change how `mailto:` links behave in chrome by visiting `chrome://settings/handlers` or `Chrome Settings->Content Settings->Manage Handlers...`

Possibly read [this](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/forms/a/aamailtobroke.htm)